# Mongoose query returning empty array in response

Tags: mongodb, mean-stack, mean

This is Morning Star schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var morningStarSchema = new Schema({
    title : {type: String, lowercase : true, required  :true},
    visit :  {type: String, lowercase : true, required  :true},
    Sightseeing : {type: String, lowercase : true, required  :true},
    image : {type: String},
    price : {type: String},
})


module.exports = mongoose.model('morningStar',morningStarSchema)
```

2. API for Morning Star schema

created database in MongoDB with collections lets cruise and snow vacations with data in it , but when I do get request I get an empty array

```
var morningStar = require('../models/morningstar')

module.exports = function (router) {

router.post('/lets-cruise', function(req, res) {
    var user = new morningStar();

    user.title = req.body.title;
    user.visit    = req.body.visit;
    user.Sightseeing = req.body.Sightseeing;
    user.image = req.body.image;
    user.price = req.body.price

    user.save();
    res.send('User created')
});

router.get('/snow-vacations', function(req, res){

morningStar.find(function(err, company) {
    if (err)
        {
        res.send(err);

        } else {
            res.json(company);
        }// return all nerds in JSON format
   });
});

return router;

}
```

Comment: Did you query find command in mongo shell whether some data is coming

Comment: yes i got data but getting and empty array while i query via mongoose